# How do I configure CloudFront to update SPA from S3 when updated?

Tags: amazon-s3, create-react-app, service-worker, amazon-cloudfront, workbox

I have a React SPA application on S3.  I'm fronting that with CloudFront solely to get an SSL certificate with a custom domain - I honestly don't really care about the caching functionality of CloudFront for this, although I suppose it's a nice perk.

Everything works fine, except when I do an update to the S3 bucket, the page remains cached in Chrome.  If I clear the application memory in Chrome, it goes out and gets the most recent version.

I'm deploying the app by creating a production build, and then uploading everything to S3 and issuing a CF invalidation:

```
  echo "Pushing to S3."
  aws s3 sync --acl public-read ./ s3://${DEPLOY_BUCKET} --metadata-directive REPLACE --cache-control 'max-age=0,public,s-maxage=2'

  echo "Invalidating CloudFront cache."
  aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ${DEPLOY_DISTRIBUTION} --paths '/' '/index.html' '/login' '/*'
```

The request to CloudFront seems to return reasonable headers to me:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=0,public,s-maxage=2
content-length: 716
content-type: text/html
date: Wed, 18 May 2022 17:15:36 GMT
etag: "660fb0d86eb442f658af12ead96b2c83"
last-modified: Wed, 18 May 2022 16:55:25 GMT
server: AmazonS3
via: 1.1 ....cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: eLXohvep_...==
x-amz-cf-pop: BOS50-C1
x-amz-version-id: 8V0DR...
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
```

Specifically - the cache-control header shows a max-age of 0, so I thought that should tell Chrome to not cache things and always go out and check for a new version.

CloudFront is setup to use the origin headers, so it should be pulling those from S3.

What am I missing?  How do I get Chrome/CloudFront/S3 to always check for the latest version of the application?

Comment: I should add that in addition to the page not updating, the etag doesn't update either until I clear the application memory in Chrome.

Comment: Does your single page application also have a service worker (for use as a PWA)? Those can be tricky with precaching, making debugging standard client caching harder.

Comment: hm... It does.  Honestly it's a pretty stock implementation of `registerServiceWorker()` that one of our devs ripped from somewhere.  Disabling it seems to get around the problem, but is there a way to get it to respect the cache-control settings?  I.e. even if you have this in local cache, if it's older than X you should still try and check for a new version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the cache headers on CloudFront are fine, and disabling `registerServiceWorker()` fixes your caching issues, we can point blame to the service worker keeping stale content.

`registerServiceWorker()` is likely from `react-scripts < 4.0.0`, which doesn't allow you to configure the service worker without ejecting or using a workaround. If you cannot upgrade, you may simply just want to unregister or remove the service worker.

If you upgrade to `react-scripts >= 4.0.0`, you can [modify the workbox config from the PWA Create React App template](https://github.com/cra-template/pwa/blob/fc9613279681a06606f90514926b8078db629ec6/packages/cra-template-pwa/template/src/service-worker.js) to use the [`NetworkFirst` Workbox strategy](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies/#network-first-network-falling-back-to-cache). After upgrading, the precache and the waiting state of the service worker may still be too aggressive for your liking, in which case you should [see if someone ran into the same PWA issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues?q=label%3A%22issue%3A%20question%20%3E%20PWA%22).

[Learn more about progressive web apps in Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/)

[Learn more about how to troubleshoot Workbox](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/troubleshooting-and-logging/)

Comment: This is fantastic @evelynhathaway thank you.  For now, we're just going to leave things disabled, as I'm not quite sure why the developer added the service worker to begin with.  But this is great stuff if we need to add it back in.